# SAML IDP and SP at the same time with IS 4.6.0

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Can I configure WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0 as an IDP for my own SAML applications and, at the same time, configure IS as a SAML service provider to an external IDP?

I would like to achieve the following:
user access my own SAML SP, which sends an AuthnRequest to my local WSO2 IDP, which in turn forwards the user to the external IDP for authentication. And after authentication with the external IDP returns to my own SAML SP application.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario seems only possible with WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and the new "identity bus" feature.